# filtering issue with a django template with two querysets - django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django template that I want to use to filter objects in a query sets. I have a group that I want to add new members to. I have a list of member objects that are used to keep track of the groups members that were added when the group was created. The members were added by displaying a list of users friends with a checkbox next to their names. I now want to display a list of friends that are not already members of the group and then add them to the group if they are selected. I am getting an issue with the html template filtering system that I have created to just show the list of friends that are not already members... can anyone help me figure this out. I have all the code below:

here is the queries that were passed:

```
# grab the group members
members = Member.objects.filter(group = group).all()
# grab all of the friends fo the logged in user
friender = Friend.objects.filter(user = user.username).all()
friended = Friend.objects.filter(friend = user).all()
friends = friender | friended
# the required parameters for this form
parameters = {
     'friends':friends,
     'members':members,
     'group':group,
     'message':message,
}
return render(request, 'groups/add_members.html', parameters)
```

Now here is the html template :

```
{% extends "general/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Create Group</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for friend in friends %}
          {% for member in members %}
            {% if member.user.username != friend.friend.username %}
              {% if member.user.username != friend.user %}
                {% if friend.user == user.username %}
                  <p>
                    {{ friend.friend.username }}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{friend.friend.username}}" value="{{friend.friend.username}}">
                  </p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if friend.friend == user %}
                  <p>
                    {{ friend.user }}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="{{friend.user}}" value="{{friend.user}}">
                  </p>
                {% endif %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the list of friends and members that exist right now

```
logged in user omar
friends: hani, assad, rana, amer 
members: hani, assad
```

here is what is displaying:

[image]

Here are the models:

```
# the following are models for accepted friend requests
class Friend(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=22, default='current user')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class UserActivity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    expense = models.ForeignKey(Expense, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='some action')
    reference = models.IntegerField(default = '101', null = True)
    category = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    # 1 = unseen
    # 2 = seen
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
# Member stores all of the different members to each of the created groups
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, default=1 , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    # 1 = member
    # 2 - host
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: please add your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to debug without models, but you could simplify your code like this:

1. Create list of members:

   ```
   members = [member.user.username for member in Member.objects.filter(group = group)]
   ```
2. Change HTML template to this. You check if `friend` is not in the `members` list and if `True` you display him:

   ```
   {% extends "general/header.html" %}
   {% block content %}
     <h1>Create Group</h1>
     <p>{{ message }}</p>
     <form method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {% for friend in friends %}
         {% if friend.friend.username not in members %}
           <p>
             {{ friend.friend.username }}
             <input type="checkbox" name="{{friend.friend.username}}" value="{{ friend.friend.username }}">
           </p>
         {% endif %}
         {% if friend.user not in members %}
           <p>
             {{ friend.user }}
             <input type="checkbox" name="{{friend.user}}" value="{{ friend.user }}">
           </p>
         {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

This will show only users that are currently not members of the group.

Other remarks:

- There is no need to use `.all()` after filter. You're already filtering which is by definition not all.
- Try to avoid nested loops and nested ifs if possible. Sometimes you cannot avoid them.

Comment: I was trying to avoid nesting but i couldnt figure out a solution yesterday. I will try your solution and see if that works. It looks like it will work tho.